# Compute the volume of a sphere with a cylindric hole

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry

Imagine, in the sphere $K:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\ |\ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4\}$ there is a cylindrical hole. It is given by $H:=\{(x,y,z)\in K\ |\ x^2+y^2 \leq 2x\}$.

> How would you compute the volume of $K\setminus H$ ?

I know, how to compute it with Cavalieri's principle, but it takes very long and the result doesn't look nice, so I wonder, if there's a nice solution.

Comment: $x^2+y^2\le 2x$ doesn't look like a cylinder to me :)

Comment: Also, if that $x$ wasn't there I would compute the volume via integration by shells, but there are probably other equally good methods.

Comment: $x^2+y^2-2x+1\le 1$ i.e. $(x-1)^2+y^2 \le 1$ is a cylinder with vertical axis passing through the $x,y$ plane at $(1,0).$ So that cylinder does go through the given sphere of radius $2$ to cut a hole.

Comment: typo: "copmute"

Comment: To copmute something involves silencing it by  police officer.

Comment: What about using cylindrical coordinates:
\begin{align}
\text{Volume }&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\cos \theta}^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta+2\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta\;?
\end{align}

Comment: You should look at "The napkin ring problem" for some insights...

Answer (score 0):

I would compute sphere volume minus included cylinder volume minus 2*spherecap volume  . Where spherecap volume = sphere solid angle minus cone.

Comment: The included cylinder here has a non-flat top since it's off center. So this idea might be hard to set up as an integral.

Comment: is it off center ? I don't see.  integral: it cylinder axe is z, is seems doable to integrate Zsphere(x,y).

Comment: See my comment to original post. The cylinder axis is perpendicular to the $x,y$ plane passing through $(1,0)$ which is not the sphere center. That's what I meant by its being "off center".

Comment: Wow, that's invisible ! do add this in the original question !

Comment: Fabrice-- In ther original question the cylinder is given as $x^2+y^2 \le 2x.$ After moving the $2x$ to the other side and completing the square one gets the inside of a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(1,0)$ in the $x,y$ plane, which in 3-d is a cylinder. I think this doesn't need to be added to the original question, except maybe for emphasis.

Comment: Right. I confess I just saw the questioning about whether it was a typo :-/ .

Answer (score 0):

The range of $x=0 \ldots 2$ from the cylinder. The range of $y = - \sqrt{x (2-x)} \ldots \sqrt{x (2-x)}$. The height of the cap on the surface is $z=\pm \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$.

So the volume is

$$ V = 2 \int \limits_{0}^{2} \int \limits_{-\sqrt{x(2-x)}}^{\sqrt{x(2-x)}} \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} {\rm d}y {\rm d}x = \frac{16 (3\pi-4)}{9} $$